# MediaPlayer setVideoScallingMode

Tags: android

I have a working android program that streams movies, what I would like is to make sure that the video being played was scaled correctly.

tried using mediaPlayer.setVideoScalingMode

have tried both VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING, and VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT.

But each time the code gets executed the mediaPlayer fails as soon as it executes the setViewScalingMode command.

I have tried using various calculations in code, to get the right scaling but this does not work very well.

I have coded similar in Objective-C and it works fine on the IPAD, so if anyone has any ideas for Android it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

The reason this does not work is that it requires api level 19, I tried running this with an earlier api for support purposes but alas it would not work.